# How can I convert JsString into &str in Rust WASM?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

How can I convert an instance of type [`js_sys::JsString`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/js_sys/struct.JsString.html) into `&str` within Rust WebAssembly code?

Background: I'd like to convert the code found in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18197341) into Rust. I struggle to pass the output of [`js_sys::encode_uri_component`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/js_sys/fn.encode_uri_component.html) as the value parameter to [`web_sys::Element::set_attribute`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.Element.html#method.set_attribute):

```
let url = JsString::from("data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,");
url = url.concat(&js_sys::encode_uri_component(&text));

let anchor = document.create_element("a")
    .and_then(|elm| elm.dyn_into::<web_sys::HtmlElement>())?;
anchor.set_attribute("href", &url)?;  // Error: expected `str`, found struct `js_sys::JsString`
// ...
```

Comment: `let x: String = url.into()`

Comment: @Shepmaster: That works fine indeed. No idea why I didn't try it that way. Please add the comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by user Shepmaster in the question comments above the solution is that simple:

```
let x: String = url.into()
```